# Object is of type unknown error when using Typescript with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a chatbox with React using typescript and Firebase. This is my code for the Room and Message component:

```
function ChatRoom() {
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });
  console.log(messages);
  return (
    <>
      {messages &&
        messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}
    </>
  );
}

function ChatMessage(props: any) {
  const { text, uid, photoURL } = props.message;

  return (
    <>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

when I specify `key={msg.id}` it says that `Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571`. I tried to create an interface for the Mesaage which is:

```
interface Message {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  createdAt: { nanoseconds: number; seconds: number };
}
```

But I'm not able to understand how do I specify this Interface to the `msg` in the map function.
I tried:
`{messages && messages.map(msg: Message => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}`
but that didn't work too. I am new to TypeScript and React and any help would be appreciated. Much thanks.

Comment: `{messages && messages.map((msg: Message) => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}`

Comment: gives this error: ```Argument of type '(msg: Message) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'msg' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Message'.```

Comment: what is the value of `message `?

Comment: console log of messages array gives this```Array(3)
0:
createdAt: t {seconds: 1603996200, nanoseconds: 0}
id: "LlyqGWDBmnQAGqdJjFwG"
text: "Nope :("
__proto__: Object
1: {text: "plsss", createdAt: t, id: "gEtenzx09HLPUUzg4SRR"}
2: {text: "newwwww", createdAt: t, id: "WfLWpeU4dXTYCt0zdVEN"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your interface and [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) whithin your map function

```
messages.map(msg => key = {(msg as ChatMessage).id} message = {msg})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Typescript and react-query, same error `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

Installing this devDependency "**@types/react-query**" helped me somehow. I am using VS Code editor and I think that helped with type suggestions.

`npm i --save-dev @types/react-query`